# spark write parquet file. How can I specify the row groups size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, fastparquet

I am struggling to find how to specify the row group size of the parquet file writer in the Spark API.

I found one way to do this which is to use the fast parquet python module that has this option :

from fastparquet import write

write has the parameter:
 row_group_offsets

Also, what is the optimal number for row_group size ?

Thanks to fast parquet, I did some experiments. Picking a row_groupsize of 1 million is ten times faster than 10 000 for instance. But if I pick more than 1 million, it starts to slow down my simple queries.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Parquet parameters are part of the hadoop options and can be set before the parquet write command like this:

```
val sc : SparkContext // An existing SparkContext.
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("parquet.block.size", 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto. It seems that also modifying the number of partition (which by default is 600) helped. Now I can see with parquet-tools that the block size of my parquet files has increased. I have 1 million row by block.

But loading my data and doing a simple count operation is still quite slow with spark.
The dataset I am talking about has only 4 millions rows and 15 columns

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Roberto. It seems that also modifying the number of partition (which by default is 600) helped. Now I can see with parquet-tools that the block size of my parquet files has increased. I have 1 million row by block.

But loading my data and doing a simple count operation is still quite slow with spark.
The dataset I am talking about has only 4 millions rows and 15 columns